# I want to set hiredate >2000 for every row

Tags: oracle

```
 update emp set to_char(hiredate,'yy'):=01
   where hiredate='20-MAR-96';

   update emp set to_char(hiredate,'yy'):=01
                  *
```

> ERROR at line 1:    ORA-00927: missing equal sign

Comment: What do you want to do? say you have a row with 20-MAR-96, what should be the final value?

Comment: `to_char(hiredate,'yy')` isnt a field, and you cant update a expresion,

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you are looking for?

```
update emp
set hiredate = to_date('2001'||to_char(hiredate, 'mmddhh24MISS'), 'yyyymmddhh24MISS');
```

This way `month`, `day` and `time` remain the same, only the `year` is updated to `2001` for every row. If you want to update only certain rows, you can add that condition to the where clause.

Comment: [**DEMO**](http://rextester.com/FLO46070) Yes, I got the same idea. Just I think OP want set it to `2001`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza right, I updated my answer. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10008.htm#SQLRF01708), the `update` statement should be written in this way:

```
update emp
set hireDate = ...
where ...
```